# Proving that something is a topology on $X$

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,\mathcal{T})$ be a topological space. Let $A$ be a set such that $A \subseteq X.$ Show that the family $\mathcal{T}_{A} := \{U \cup (V \cap A) \mid U, V \in  \mathcal{T} \}$ is a topology on $X.$

The only problem I have is to show that $X \in \mathcal{T}_{A}$  and that $\emptyset \in \mathcal{T}_{A}.$

Comment: There are two problems with that. In the first place, $X\subset T_A$ makes no sense. In the second place, the assertion $\emptyset\subset X$ holds for *every* set $X$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos OP clearly means $\in$ instead of $\subset$ in both cases.

Answer (score 2):

$X = X \cup (\emptyset \cap A) \in \mathcal{T}_A$.

$\emptyset  =\emptyset \cup (\emptyset \cap A) \in \mathcal{T}_A$.

I don't see any issue there. We just use $X,\emptyset \in \mathcal{T}$ directly plus the definitions.

Comment: Indeed, i did not see that. i have one more question, is T and $T_A$ the same topology?

Comment: @mode100 if $A$ is not open, this is another, larger topology.